# Formatting string by braces with braces escaping

Tags: python, string, parsing, python-re

I have a string, that contains expresions in braces:

```
string = "3+3={3+3}"
```

I want to find all expresions and replace them by result of expression (using eval).
Also I want to make some kind of braces escaping mechanism.
I can do it by myself:

```
final = ""
opened_eval = False
short_escaping = False
long_escaping = False
inner_string = ""
for letter in string:
    if opened_eval:
        if letter == "}":
            final += eval(inner_string, kwargs)
            inner_string = ""
            opened_eval = False
        else:
            inner_string+=letter
    elif short_escaping:
        opened+=letter
        short_escaping=False
    elif long_escaping:
        if letter == "|":
            long_escaping=False
        else:
            opened+=letter
    else:
        if letter == "\\":
            short_escaping=True
        elif letter == "|":
            long_escaping=True
        elif letter=="{":
            opened_eval = True
        else:
            final+=letter
```

```
>>> print(final)
3+3=6
```

But I care about, how quickly does it work, so I want to use C function.
I tryed to do that with re.finditer (`r"\{\w+\}"`), but I don't know, how can I make escaping with re. So I need something like this:

```
for expression in find(r"a = {get_a()} \{text in braces\} b = {get_b()}"):
    print(expression.text, expression.start, expression.end)
```

```
{get_a()} 5 13
{get_b()} 38 46
```

Comment: That's a great way to allow script injection attacks. Imagine what would happen if that string contained malicious code, eg `os.rmtree`.  You can use `eval(f'f"{string}"')` to convert that string into an f-string (there's a duplicate for this) but you have to make absolutely certain those strings are sanitized, especially if the strings come from user input

Comment: Escaping doesn't work with your code either, since you never use `opened`. If you want to use the code to show what you are trying to do, make it sure does that. But some kind of description would be better if you want people to understand. Question: do you intend to allow `{` inside `{...}` expressions?

Answer (score 0):

Faster way to do this:

After `import re`, define a string:

```
string = "3+3={3+3}, 7:4={7/4}, etc.."
```

find all the arguments in the brackets:

```
equations = re.findall("\{[^\{\}]*\}", string)
>>>['{3+3}', '{7/4}']
```

solve the equations:

```
results = [list(eval(equation))[0] for equation in equations]
>>>[6, 1.75]
```

finally replace the brackets in the string (`sub`) and `format` the string with the results:

```
re.sub("\{[^\{\}]*\}","{}",string).format(*results)
>>>'3+3=6, 7:4=1.75, etc..'
```